# Save and restore Semtech SX1276 state

Tags: embedded, lora, lorawan

for technical (safety mainly) reasons, I have to shutdown completely the RF module (sx1276) from time to time for five or less minutes (once or two times per day). Since my LoRaWAN stack is already initialized and my sessions keys still valid after first join, is it possible to simply save all sx1276 registers, shut it down and up, and restore them back to be able to continue doing uplinks without having to reinitialize the whole stack?
if yes, is there any care to take about the order in which I have to write the registers?

is there any other technical cleaner method to do a simple radio only restart?

Regards

Comment: This is really "too broad" to be an answerable question.  Most LoRaWAN stacks configure most of what matters on the radio before every operation, because so much typically changes (frequency, spreading factor, bandwidth, IQ inversion, how many symbols to detect preamble for, etc).  If you truly shut the chip down in a way that loses *all* state you'd also need to reinitialize basics like setting LoRa modulation as the mode, configuring the preamble code and various options, etc - but you probably already have code to do that on initial startup, too.

Comment: This comes down to needing to really understand your particular LoRaWAN stack, both in terms of how it handles the radio and in terms of understanding how the *protocol state* is maintained in the processor with only temporary derived details being injected into the radio.